# htpassword for all incoming traffic except one specific url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm using htpassword to protect one of my servers. I would like to redirect traffic coming to a single subdomain to another domain while keep the htpassword active for all other traffic.

I'm struggling to find a resource with any information about doing this, can anyone help with links advice or code...

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/root/.htpasswd
AuthName "Members Only"
AuthType Basic

# Access Restriction:
Require user Administrator [password]
order deny,allow
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a VirtualHost config for that domain then use
RewriteEngine (RewriteRules RewriteCond) to redirect your {REQUEST_URI} to another url.

Cheers